# Systemd oneshot service doesn't return

Tags: debian, systemd

I have a systemd oneshot service defined like that :

```
[Unit]
Description=Firewall
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=yes
ExecStart=/etc/iptables/iptables start
ExecStop=/etc/iptables/iptables stop

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Of course, the script is tested and works : it adds rules when started and removes them when stopped. My problem is that when I try to use

```
systemctl start iptables.service
```

it never returns. I have to ^C it, and it really added the iptables rules. What could be my problem ?

Comment: `Type=oneshot` will not return from start until the ExecStart command returns. Is that the case for your iptables script? Perhaps `Type=simple` is possible, as `systemctl start` returns immediately, though any dependant units will perhaps start before iptables has been set up.

Comment: yup, my original script did return (after applying all the rules) quite swiftly. I completely changed how the script works, and it's now fine. but I didn't find a solution to my problem. it *should* have been working from the start.